# How to attack Oblivious Transfer from a malicious sender that can deviate from the protocol

Tags: rsa, protocol-design, attack, oblivious-transfer

I am looking at at the $1–2 \space \text{oblivious transfer}$ that is described here: [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oblivious_transfer#:~:text=In%20cryptography%2C%20an%20oblivious%20transfer,Rabin.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oblivious_transfer#:%7E:text=In%20cryptography%2C%20an%20oblivious%20transfer,Rabin.)

I want to show that a malicious sender (Alice) can attack this protocol if it can deviate from it, namely, send a wrong RSA key pair, and learn the secret bit $b$.

If the sender (Alice) sends $e$ such that $gcd(e, \phi(N)) \neq 1$, then the RSA key is not valid, but the receiver (Bob) can't efficiently know this without the factorization of $N$.

However, I don't exactly understand how sending such an invalid input $e$ helps.

Since $e$ and $\phi(N)$ aren't coprime, then $k^e$ from the protocol that the receiver sends is not exactly random. But how does it help to understand who is $b$?

Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to show that a malicious sender (Alice) can attack this protocol if it can deviate from it, namely, send a wrong RSA key pair, and learn the secret bit $b$.

You can, in fact, show this (or, rather, the OT would require a ZK proof by Alice that $\gcd(e, \phi(N)) = 1$)

> However, I don't exactly understand how sending such an invalid input $e$ helps.

If $\gcd(e, \phi(N)) > 1$, then not all values $z$ have $e$th roots, that is, sometimes there won't be a value $y$ with $y^e = z$.  And, if you know the factorization, this is easy to test.

So, when Alice gets the value $v = (x_b + k^e) \bmod N$, she can compute $v - x_0$ and $v - x_1$.  The correct one will be an $e$th root; the wrong one will likely not be - if it is not, then she will then know $b$.

One issue that Alice will run into is that, in this case, she would not be able to unambiguously recover $k$; this would prevent her from being able to complete the protocol. However, the damage has already been done.

Comment: Thanks! Could you clarify why the correct one will be an $e$th root, and the wrong one will likely not be?

Comment: @GabiG: well, if $b=0$, then $v - x_0 = k^e$, Alice doesn't know what $k$ is, but it will exist, and hence $v - x_0$ will have a $e$th root.  In contrast, $v - x_1$ is effectively a random value, and random values have an aproximately $1/e$ probability (if $e$ is prime and $e$ is a factor of only one of $p-1, q-1$; otherwise, it's more complicated) of having an $e$th root, that is, being $k'^e$ for some value $k'$